# R dataframe has date as part of a column name and I want specify the most recent two columns without typing them each time

Tags: r, dataframe, date, datetime, r-colnames

I am trying to automate a report that I am running manually each week. I have a data frame called **p_wide** where each week a new column is being added and column names contain dates that represent when each of those columns are added, for example:

```
id   col_2022_09_04   col_2022_09_11   col_2022_09_18   col_2022_09_25
---  --------------   --------------   --------------   --------------
01        0.3               0.8              0.9              0.1
02        0.6               0.1              0.4              0.5
03        0.2               0.1              0.3              0.4
04        0.1               0.7              0.4              0.9
```

In my report, I create a subset of p_wide dataframe using a filter. For example:

```
p_mover <- p_wide %>% filter(abs(col_2022_09_18 - col_2022_09_25) > .33)
```

Is there a way that I can specify those two columns above without manually typing each week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column names are always of the form `col_yyyy_mm_dd` then here's some code that extracts the dates, finds the last and last but one and uses these with `!!` to do the filtering. The dates are assumed to be in order with the most recent as the last one.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

p_wide <- read.table(text="id   col_2022_09_04   col_2022_09_11   col_2022_09_18   col_2022_09_25
01        0.3               0.8              0.9              0.1
02        0.6               0.1              0.4              0.5
03        0.2               0.1              0.3              0.4
04        0.1               0.7              0.4              0.9", header = T)

# Get the names of the columns
column_names <- names(p_wide)
# Create a regex to look for dates of the form yyyy_mm_dd
dates_regex <- regex('[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}')
# Find the dates
dates <- str_match(string = column_names, dates_regex)[,1] %>% na.omit() 
# Find the last date and make a symbol for use later
last_date_column <- sym(paste0('col_', max(dates)))
# Find the last but one date - again as a symbol
last_date_but_one_column <- sym(paste0('col_', head(tail(dates, 2), 1)))

# Filter using the calculated variables
p_wide %>% filter(abs(!!last_date_but_one_column - !!last_date_column) > .33)

# id col_2022_09_04 col_2022_09_11 col_2022_09_18 col_2022_09_25
# 1  1            0.3            0.8            0.9            0.1
# 2  4            0.1            0.7            0.4            0.9
```